# Setting a QueuePolicy from Cloudformation does not take effect at Stack creation - but setting an identical policy after creation takes effect

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm trying to create a queue and a subscription to it from an (existing) SNS Topic. All resources in the same account. I know that, in order to do so, the queue needs to have a QueuePolicy that allows SNS to `SendMessage` to the queue.

However, I've found that the QueuePolicy I've created via Cloudformation does not appear to be respected - messages are not delivered to the queue, and Cloudwatch logs from the Topic report that delivery failed because permission was denied. If I re-apply that same policy after creation, however, it takes effect and messages are delivered.

Here's what I tried first:

```
$ cat template.yaml
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Description:
  ...

Parameters:
  TopicParameter:
    Type: String

Resources:
  Queue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue

  Subscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    DependsOn: QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      Endpoint:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - "Queue"
          - "Arn"
      Protocol: "sqs"
      RawMessageDelivery: "true"
      TopicArn: !Ref TopicParameter

  QueuePolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: '1'
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action: "SQS:SendMessage"
            Resource: !Ref Queue
            Condition:
              ArnEquals:
                aws:SourceArn: !Ref TopicParameter
      Queues:
        - !Ref Queue

Outputs:
  QueueArn:
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - "Queue"
        - "Arn"
    Export:
      Name: "QueueArn"
$ aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name my-test-stack --template-body file://template.yaml --parameters ParameterKey=TopicParameter,ParameterValue=<topicArn>
{
    "StackId": "<stackId>"
}
# ...wait...
$ aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name my-test-stack --query "Stacks[0] | Outputs[0] | OutputValue"
"<queueArn>"
# Do some trivial substitution to get the QueueUrl - it's *probably* possible via the CLI, but I don't think you need me to prove that I can do it
$ aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url <queueUrl> --attribute-names ApproximateNumberOfMessages --query "Attributes.ApproximateNumberOfMessages"
"0"
# The above is consistently true, even if I wait and retry after several minutes. I've confirmed that messages *are* being published from the topic via other subscriptions
$ aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url <queueUrl> --attribute-names Policy --query "Attributes.Policy"
"{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"1\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"SQS:SendMessage\",\"Resource\":\"<queueUrl>\",\"Condition\":{\"ArnEquals\":{\"aws:SourceArn\":\"<topicArn>\"}}}]}"
$ aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url <queueUrl> --attribute-names Policy --query "Attributes.Policy" | | perl -pe 's/^.(.*?).$/$1/' | perl -pe 's/\\"/"/g' | python -m json.tool
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "<topicArn>"
                }
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Resource": "<queueUrl>",
            "Sid": "1"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

At this point, everything looks correct. If I go to the AWS Console, I see a QueuePolicy on the queue that is exactly what I expect - but no messages.

If I *re-apply* the QueuePolicy, though...

```
$ aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url <queueUrl> --attribute-names Policy --query "Attributes" > policyInFile
$ cat policyInFile
{
    "Policy": "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"1\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"SQS:SendMessage\",\"Resource\":\"<queueUrl>\",\"Condition\":{\"ArnEquals\":{\"aws:SourceArn\":\"<topicArn>\"}}}]}"
}
$ aws sqs set-queue-attributes --queue-url <queueUrl> --attributes policyInFile
```

Then, a few seconds later, the queue starts receiving messages.

Even weirder, I can reproduce this same behaviour by doing the following:

- set up the Stack
- going to the queue in the console
- confirm that the queue is not receiving messages
- hit "Edit" on the queue's Policy
- hit "Save" (that is - *not changing anything in the policy*)
- observe the queue receiving messages

How can I make the QueuePolicy in the Cloudformation Stack take effect at the time of Queue Creation?

Comment: I *think* I should have used the URL for the `resource` in the QueuePolicy (which I just found by diffing the "before" and "after"), rather than the ARN. Confirming now...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I should have used the Queue's **ARN** for the `resource`, not the URL. I guess that, when setting a QueuePolicy for a Queue (via Console or CLI but *not* via Cloudformation), the `resource` field is overwritten to the ARN of the queue in question.